# Is there a way to get dynamically get all table field names using jOOQ?

Tags: java, jooq

The codegen generated `TableImpl`s contain methods like `getIndexes`, `getPrimaryKey`, `getKeys`.

There is no method to get all table fields (`TableField`) like `getFields`.

Is there another way to check programmatically if e.g. `name` is an actual column of a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get a field by its name and check if you actually got the field back

```
if (TableName.TABLENAME.field("name") != null) {
    System.out.println("The field is there: " + TableName.TABLENAME.field("name").getName());
} else {
    System.out.println("There is no field with that name.");
}
```

It's also possible to get all the fields using the `fieldsRow()` method:

```
Row fields = TableName.TABLENAME.fieldsRow();

for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(fields.field(i).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> There is no method to get all table fields (TableField) like getFields.

Due to historic naming reasons, the method is called [`Table.fields()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#fields--) not `Table.getFields()`.

> Is there another way to check programmatically if e.g. name is an actual column of a table?

[wallek876 alredy provided the right answer to this part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54756178/521799).

Comment: Thx Lukas for explaining the no `getFields` method due to historic naming. Maybe it can be added and just calls `fields()` internally. Is useful when using Kotlin.

Comment: Btw, can't you add the desired method using an extension function in Kotlin?

Comment: Yes, that's also an option to explore. Thx!